# inumtable.List[Object] found required List[Contact]

Tags: scala

I'm having some problems with the following code:

```
object GestorContactos {
  private var listaContantocs:List[Contacto] = Nil
  def insertarOrd(c:Contacto):List[Contacto]=listaContantocs={
    var aux:List[Contacto]=listaContantocs.sortBy(_.edad)
    aux.filter(x=>x.edad<c.edad)::c::(aux.filter(x=>x.edad>c.edad))
  }
```

`aux.filter(x=>x.edad<c.edad)`returns List[Contacto] and the same does `aux.filter(x=>x.edad>c.edad)`.

The problem is that when I try to add both results with a `Contacto` Object (var c) on a single list the following error appears:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : List[Contacto]
 required: Contacto
```

It seems that `listaContantocs`, a inmutable List[Contacto], does not like the return type List[Object]. Is there any way I could cast List[Object] to List[Contacto]?

Comment: A couple of problems here. First, `::` prepends a **single** element to a `List`, as such: `aux.filter(x=>x.edad<c.edad)::c::(aux.filter(x=>x.edad>c.edad))` is adding `aux.filter(x=>x.edad<c.edad)` as a single element to the `List` instead of contacting the whole `List`, which results in a `List[Any]`; you can do this instead `aux.filter(x=>x.edad<c.edad) ::: (c :: (aux.filter(x=>x.edad>c.edad)))`. - Second, unnecessary use of `vars` - Third, `=listaContantocs={` this doesn't make sense. - Fourth, the code is uneradable due the absence of white spaces. - Fifth, please code in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are combing different element types `List[Contacto]` and `Contacto` with operator `::`.

The following is what you want

```scala
aux.filter(x=>x.edad<c.edad) ++ (c :: (aux.filter(x=>x.edad>c.edad)))
```